# Approve workflow when approvals are > 50%

Tags: workflow, approval-process

Basically we have 4 people that have to approve something, but I think it should go out to all 4 people and once 2 people approve it, it can move on to the next phase. Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought: create a hidden field that increments each time a person approves.  Use a separate workflow to perform the increment. Set countfield to value+1.  Then, set approval field to approved once the count is greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any reason this won't work! I will report back with any issues.

Comment: You could use a CEWP with a document ready function to check the value of your approval count. Then, when it reaches the desired number, execute an update on a flag column in your list to trigger the workflow. This way you do not have any paused timer jobs, which can be a pain if you have too many.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the thought @lazoDev "This way you do not have any paused timer jobs, which can be a pain if you have too many." I am mainly concerned with the fact that (they)"...can be a pain if you have too many".

Thanks

Comment: You do not want to have too many running processes. Just because it is paused does not mean it is not running in the background on your w3wp worker processes. This can cause slow down on the farm, and potential lockups which can be a nightmare if something gets corrupted in the process. I have seen it happen before.